# Using git for multiple separate projects whose files share a common directory

Tags: git, github

I would like to use git for version control of some files, but I cannot figure out best practice in my situation. Let me set up the problem first, and then explain my failed attempts at solutions:

I use an optical design program called CodeV, which is command-line based. I write custom macros ("sequence files" in CodeV speak) in its programming language. These files are used to analyze/design optical systems, so they should be available to every instance of CodeV. I have all of my custom macros in a single directory. To run them from CodeV, I simply type `run filename.seq` in the command line of CodeV, because I have added the `CUSTOM_MACROS` directory to my sequence file search path in CodeV. Easy.

This has been a very verbose way of saying I have many potentially unrelated files in a single directory.

Now, these files are a work in progress, and I'd like to work on them with my coworkers using GitHub. So, in my `CUSTOM_MACROS` directory, I might have this:

```
macro1.seq
macro2.seq
...
sharedmacro3.seq
sharedmacro4.seq
```

I want separate version control of each file, and I assume that means separate repos on GitHub. How do I implement Git locally to achieve this?

I have tried to use one repo in `CUSTOM_MACROS` and add all of the files, then use branches for each specific file:

```
git add -A
git commit -am 'Add all of the files'
git checkout -b sharedmacro3
```

*make some changes*

```
git commit -am 'Changed some stuff in sharedmacro3.seq'
git checkout master
git merge sharedmacro3
```

This is fine, but now if I want to create a new macro, I add the file, and create a new branch for that project, but it inherits the history from the other file commits. I don't want this behavior, I just want the commit history of that file/project.

What is a better way to go about this? Is what I want possible?

Then when I want to add this repo to GitHub, it contains all of my custom macros, so my coworker pulls in all my files when he just wants sharemacro3.

I am probably missing something basic as I am relatively new to Git. If so, please point me to the resource so I can learn. There are many similar problems but none that really seem to match my specific use case.

To reiterate: how do I use git to track multiple projects whose files are in the same directory, and then share those projects with coworkers using GitHub?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how much this is going to help, but that's the way how Git works. It typically is used to versionize all of the files in the repo's directory. So if all your files are in the same directory, they will be part of the same repo.

The *branch* workaround is awkward and won't scale well, as you have experienced.

Here are a couple of ideas:

- Can you use sub-directories in your `CUSTOM_MACROS` directory? If this was possible, then you could have one repo per sub-directory. This would allow you to versionize single files, or group files into a sub-directory if they belong together.
- If sub-directories are not an option, you could look into having multiple `CUSTOM_MACROS` directories.
- Maybe it's worth exploring the idea of having a general collection of macros in one common repo. Do you really need the granularity of having a separate version per macro file? Having one repo for all of the macros would make things a lot easier, and maybe it even provides some value. Without knowing your files and how similar they are in context, it's hard to tell.

Anyway, I would aim to keep things as simple as possible. If keeping everything in one repo, then I would use that. Is there any harm in pulling everything? Are your macros so big that storage and network speed are an issue when downloading the whole repo?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sub-directories will work for allowing separate repos. But I do need all of the files in the parent directory, because it is cumbersome to add those paths to the search path of CodeV (and there is a hard limit of 50 search paths, god only knows why).
One solution would be symbolic links in the parent directory to the actual files in the sub-directory.  (Or vice versa, I guess). The other would be to set core.worktree for each repo to be the parent directory (`CUSTOM_MACROS`).

Comment: This is quickly getting ugly :-). If you want to use sub-directories, you could use a script to copy them to the parent directory after pulling in the changes - but that becomes an issue again when you make changes locally. A single repo that has all of the macros really sounds like your best option - maybe combine it with some kind of naming convention, so that you can quickly identify the content and context of a file.